# When converting pdf to jpg using php the quality is bad

Tags: php, pdf, jpeg

This is the PHP code I am using to convert pdf to jpg and the quality of the images it outputs is very bad, so can someone help me?

```
            // Convert PDF to JPG
            $imagick = new \Imagick();
            $imagick->readImage($file_path);
            $imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
            $imagick->setCompressionQuality(100);
            $imagick->setResolution(300, 300);

            // Display converted images
            echo '<div class="">';
            foreach($imagick as $image){
                $output_file = 'uploads/' . uniqid() . '.jpg';
                $image->writeImage($output_file);
                echo '<center><div class="ConContainer"><img src="' . $output_file . '" class="preview" alt="Converted Image" />';
                echo '<a href="' . $output_file . '" class="downloadbtn" download>Download JPG</a><br/><br/><div></center>';
            }
            echo '</div>';

            // Destroy imagick object
            $imagick->clear();
            $imagick->destroy();
        }
```

I want help to fix my code.

Comment: Hello, can you please edit and made the changes for me because I am new to PHP and this is my first project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the `setImageCompressionQuality()` function can help to improve the JPG image quality.

Comment: I have tried but it did not work.